# Can I create a web server with dart/flutter available from anywhere in the world

Tags: flutter, dart, server

I want to create a web server with flutter/dart, something similar to how the following app works on android https://github.com/mvbasov/lWS. I have searched but I don't see how the server can be deployed on mobile devices. And the truth is that the server is going to be the base of my app, the main functions will be others that depend on the server. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want a server on the user's phone, for an app that would also be on the user's phone? It would seem to defeat the purpose of having a client-server application. Normally you have a single (logical) server instance which is connected to the internet. Then each individual instance of your app (the clients) would all connect to that one server

Comment: To be fair, it might be I'm just not understanding your intended architecture, but if that's the case then you'll likely need to give more details in order to receive a helpful answer

Comment: Do you know the app Zapya? That app can work like a server creating a hotspot and at the same time it works as a client of its own server.in my app the app server will not be for the user himself, but for others who want to access their information and at the same time it must function as a client to access all other servers. The main objective is decentralization, each one owns their information, it will not happen as with big corporations, that when you delete something many times the data was not really deleted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.